# how to importing the contacts from the simulator to my app table view?

Tags: iphone, methods, alert

one more question

i need to import the contacts from the i phone simulator to my app table view and i should display the details of each contact by clicking the contact from the table view is there any possibility? if it is there please give me

Comment: code is incorrect and looks horrible! why all is lowercase ??? why do you want to "pass" the method and not just use it as a utility  ?

Comment: what you actually want to do? you want to show alert on each field or you are asking how to call a method?

Comment: @giorashc : yeah that i know i typed that why now i am in my home i came from office thats why i cant copy and past you just tell me the way how to pass?

Comment: What is your question? I cannot understand at all!

Comment: @ForamMukundShah: yeah i want to call this method to different conditions where i want...

Comment: when you want to show this alert? after you filled up the textfield or before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare in declaration.h file..

```
- (void) showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message;
```

and in declaration.m file use like bellow...

```
- (void) showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

use like bellow..

```
if ([firstName.text length]==0){

     [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Empty Field" mesage:@"Please Enter First Name"];

} else if([sndname.text length]==0){
     [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Empty Field" mesage:@"Please Enter Second Name"];

}
```

Comment: @pras johi: joshi can you remember my code which is before  i posted. in that i have written that ful uialertview code for each and every one. so for that i can use like this know? i was thiking this but i dont know how to cal the particular method thats why.

Comment: oh mate just see when you check or validate that particular textfield is empty at that time in inner side just call this method with your Field Title..